# Is it OK to publicise my Google/OAuth key?

Tags: javascript, oauth

I've updated my Google Sheets import utility that gets data from Google Sheets so that it can be used with RGraph (so it now uses the v4 API).

It seems that this new API requires an OAuth API key. Which is a bit of a ball-ache if you ask me.

Is it OK to publish this OAuth key on a website? Like in the source code of this page?

https://www.rgraph.net/tests/canvas.bar/sheets/sheets.html

If not then how would a JavaScript based import utility like this work?

The source code of the charts that are created on that page is:

```
<script>
    new RGraph.Sheets(
        'AIzaSyDCODMgxGo6q4qgkw8haCwXr__8d5r7IIg',      // OAuth key
        '1ZV79XGR0bkNmFoiQmipA-kXAujyXLsSaeHetfOrPTHA', // Spreadsheet key
        myCallback
    );

    new RGraph.Sheets(
        'AIzaSyDCODMgxGo6q4qgkw8haCwXr__8d5r7IIg',      // OAuth key
        '1ncvARBgXaDjzuca9i7Jyep6JTv9kms-bbIzyAxbaT0E', // Spreadsheet key
        'Bar chart',
        myCallback2
    );




    //
    // First charts callback
    //
    function myCallback (sheet)
    {
        var data   = sheet.get('a1:a4');
        var labels = sheet.get('b1:b4');

        bar = new RGraph.Bar({
            id: 'cvs',
            data: data,
            options: {
                xaxisLabels: labels,
                marginInner: 35
            }
        }).wave();
    }

    //
    // Second charts callback
    //
    function myCallback2 (sheet)
    {
        var data = sheet.get('b2:c13');

        bar = new RGraph.Bar({
            id: 'cvs2',
            data: data,
            options: {
                xaxisLabels: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
                backgroundGridVlines: false,
                backgroundGridBorder: false,
                xaxis: false,
                yaxis: false,
                colors: ['red', 'black']
            }
        }).wave();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't mention *ANY API KEY* inside your project files.
I would say, use a .env to maintain such keys.
webpack or any other bundler will make sure it (the key) doesn't get exposed.

Comment: It's JavaScript that runs in a webpage - so the OAuth key has to be public - ie in the page or in one of the library files included by the page. Which are all clear text.

Comment: @Richard You should probably do a (AJAX) request to PHP to get the data you need. To then use the data in Javascript. I think its normal to retrieve your data from the serverside and then use it in the front-end.

Comment: That would definitely work. I have a PHP based Google Sheets connector too that could help facilitate that: https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/sheets.html#how-to-get-data-from-google-sheets-with-php For some of my demo pages that I distribute with my softwares zip archive (that people can run on their own desktop computers) that wouldn't really work too well - unless they called the website to get the data - and I'm not really fond of that idea. My answer below details what I have done though (multiple OAuth API keys)

Answer (score 0):

I now have two keys:

1. I've got one API key for my website which is referrer restricted and also restricted to the Sheets API
2. I've got another key just for the demos which are distributed in the downloadable zip file (so anyone can run those demos on their website or local computer). This I can always regenerate if it gets abused and delete the old one. Also this is restricted to the Sheets API.